# Crawl errors "src" in the last in URL

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors

I was looking in the Google Webmaster Tools and realized the following crawl error:

> Pages that link to `http://mysite.com/articles/my-stub/src/`
>   URL: `http://mysite.com/articles/my-stub`

I wonder from where `src` is coming. My original article URL is `http://mysite.com/articles/my-stub`.

Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: Have you viewed the source code of `http://mysite.com/articles/my-stub`? If so, did you view it *after* server-side processing?

Comment: Posting your actual site would be more helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You or someone else is linking to that URL. Webmaster tools tells you where it did find that URL, so go check it.

You could also write a .htaccess rule to redirect any wrong URL to the right one.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways or places Google might have found that `/src` url. Solving it is easy, though: add a `canonical` link tag to the top of your page.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mysite.com/articles/my-stub">
```

This will tell Google that `/my-stub` is the "official" version of that page and that this is the URL it should direct people to.

[More about canonical urls](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any sitemaps submitted?  Without knowing your URL it is hard to make a call, but I would be looking at sitemaps and internal links.